# ProgressBar Spinner for Async Task doesn't work

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

My problem is that when i click button "Click" to call my API it should show my progressBar(spinner) while I'm calling API. Instead my application freeze for less than a second and then when it's done calling it shows my loading spinner for a brief time (it just flash)

Here is my code

```
private ProgressBar spinner;
public View onCreateView(...)
{
    spinner = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ...
}



private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    String pageContent = "";
    DataOutputStream wr;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        requestResult.setSuccess(false);
        HttpURLConnection connection;

        try {
            String url = "myURL";

            //I only call my Api here. I delete rest so this won't bother you

            requestResult.setSuccess(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        //Same here i delete nonimportant 

        MyResponse = new Gson().fromJson(jsonContent, MyResponse.class);
        done();
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

I've tried hounder different things it always freeze for a second and then my loading spinner flash and my content from API is shown.

Can you help me with that one, please?

My xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view_send"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/buttonSend"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: There's not enough code to see the details, but if you want to update a spinner, you need to do it in the on onProgressUpdate API, as that runs on the UI thread. Also make sure you are not sharing variables in your doInBackground and other methods, use the arguments to pass values instead.

Comment: you made your test in emulator?

Comment: Other code is just calling an API nothing else or i'm wrong? 
onProgressUpdate is not this to see progress? I just need a spinner that turns in infinity. I just need to start this spinner and stop it.
Yes i use arguments to pass my values. I access them like params[0],...

Comment: Yes i made my test in emulator

Comment: please post your layout

Comment: ProgressBar is at the end

Comment: Instead of setting visibility try `show()` and `dismis()`

Comment: I tried same as before. It's like my phone freeze for a second and then it execute all in a flash of moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this working sample, pass the `spinner` to your `MyTask` like this:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    String pageContent = "";
    DataOutputStream wr;

    private final ProgressBar progress;

    public MyTask(final ProgressBar progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        //Same here i delete nonimportant 

        MyResponse = new Gson().fromJson(jsonContent, MyResponse.class);
        done();
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Then call `new MyTask(progress).execute();`

**EDIT:** In your question you refer that your phone is freezing while calling the MyTask...
Please check this step to avoid freezing your UI in AsyncTask:

1. Do not call `MyTask` using new `MyTask().get()`
2. Try moving to `doInBackground` this part `MyResponse = new Gson().fromJson(jsonContent, MyResponse.class);  done();` this could be expensive.

Hope its helps!!

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but this still does't work it's same as before. What's with parent and textview variable? I get "variable may not been initialized"

Comment: I removed unused variable, where are you getting `variable may not been initialized`?

Comment: I did that too before. It's like this code is skipped in onPreExecute and executed in onPostExecute.  It's always the same no matter what i do..

Comment: I edited my answer the main problem is not the spinner, is why your phone is freezing, **this should not be happen using AsyncTask**

Comment: Yees!! Many many thanks g2o. Yes i called `MyTask().get()` i would never figure it out this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try the below snippet. It does not require spinner to be declared in layout file.

```
AsyncTask<String, String, String> asyncObject =
new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
    ProgressDialog progDailog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progDailog =
                new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);
        progDailog.setMessage("Loading");
        progDailog.setCancelable(false);
        progDailog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //Do background stuff here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progDailog.cancel();
        //Do post background stuff here.
    }
};
asyncObject.execute(null, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for help but it's same as before. It's like this code is skipped and executed in onPostExecute

Comment: Instead of setting visibility of the spinner, try show and cancel functions.